# Async data retrieval via input box is one step behind

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, reactjs, state

I am making a simple Wikipedia results viewer depending on the user's input.

The results list should update anytime the input box changes.

I am using `$.getJSON()` to make the call to the Wikipedia API. However, my results list doesn't update whenever the input box is changed. In fact, it seems like it's one step behind, so there must be something I don't comprehend with regards to updating the state, specifically from within an async call.

Having said that, the response does change as expected, as I can see in the console, so something is happening in the rendering of the results list that I don't comprehend.

From the React Debug Tools and the console, I can see that my array is updating as expected, as such:

[image]

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Wiki Searcher</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
var SearchBox = React.createClass({

    changeText: function () {
        this.props.changeInputText(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.searchBox).value);
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <input type="text" onChange={this.changeText} ref="searchBox"/>
        )
    }
});

var SearchItemList = React.createClass({

    render: function () {

        console.log('data:', this.props.results);
        console.log('inputtext', this.props.inputText);

        var listItems = this.props.results
            .filter(function (e, i) {
                return e.title.indexOf(this.props.inputText) !== -1;
            }.bind(this))
            .map(function (e, i) {
            return (
                <li key={i}>
                    <a href="#"><h3>{e.title}</h3></a>
                    <p>{e.snippet}</p>
                </li>
            )
        });
        return (
            <ul>
                {listItems}
            </ul>
        )
    }
});
//TODO: extract list item into its own component?
var Main = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            inputText: 'javascript',
            results: [],
        }
    },

    getWikiData: function () {

        var prependage = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&format=json&srsearch='
        var appendage = "&callback=?";
        var url = prependage + this.state.inputText + appendage;

        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            this.setState(
                {results: data.query.search}
            );
        }.bind(this));
    },

    componentDidMount: function () {
        this.getWikiData();
    },

    changeInputText: function (searchTerm) {
        this.setState({
            inputText: searchTerm,
        });
        this.getWikiData();
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <h1>Wiki Searcher</h1>
                    <SearchBox inputText={this.state.inputText} changeInputText={this.changeInputText}/>
                    <SearchItemList results={this.state.results} inputText={this.state.inputText}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Main/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BBpTtAX7K0q05tE0eicQ)

Comment: btw nice question with the  working plunker and all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary error is in your assumption that calling `setState`, in your `changeInputText` function,  will have changed `inputText`  before you call `getWikiData`.

`setState` is an async function and so the new value for `inputText` may not be set when your `getWikiData` fires.

So to fix, call `getWikiData` in the callback which will fire when the new state is updated.

```
changeInputText: function (searchTerm) {
    this.setState({
        inputText: searchTerm,
    }, () => {
       this.getWikiData();
    });  
},
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it helped me understand more about `setState()`. However, I'm still having trouble populating my list. It doesn't seem to be 'one step behind' anymore, but it does choose when to populate the list. For example, a list is produced with the query `ton`, yet nothing appears for `tony`. Any ideas?